# How do I resolve Typescript type mismatches with legacy JS code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a React project bootstrapped with create-react-app. I'm converting it to Typescript gradually and have, for example, something like:

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { TestThing } from './components/TestThing'

function stuff(a: any): void {
  console.log('stuff', a);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestThing foo="foo" bar={stuff}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and a legacy file TestThing.js

```
import React from 'react';

const DEFAULT_THING = () => {
  console.log('whatever');
};

export const TestThing = ({ foo, bar = DEFAULT_THING }) => 
    <div onClick={bar}>foo = {foo}</div>;
```

This gives the error:

```
Type '(a: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.  TS2322
```

in App.tsx as I presume Typescript is inferring `bar` can take no arguments because of it's default assignment in the legacy JS code.

How can I tell TS this is valid without having to touch that legacy JS file?

Thanks!

Comment: `DEFAULT_THING` should have the same signature as `stuff`. Either remove `a: any` from `stuff` or add it to `DEFAULT_THING` list of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is correct here. If a function is sometimes called without arguments, you really should mark it as such:

```
function stuff(a?: any): void {
  console.log('stuff', a);
}
```

Either that, or turn type checking off for that function.

Comment: Ah you're right! It was the `?` that I hadn't thought about adding. ...you have no idea how long I've been staring at this haha. Thanks so much :-)